# Getting negative value when UISlider goes left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, slider, uislider

I was trying to figure out how to get a negative value of the slider when it goes back.

When I slide from left to right it returns a positive value. I need it to return a negative value when it goes back (from right to left).

In other words, how could I detect that the slider is going back?

```
    self.borderSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];
    self.borderSlider.center = CGPointMake(self.view.centerX, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2);
    self.borderSlider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.borderSlider.maximumValue = 100.0f;
    self.borderSlider.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.borderSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(borderSliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous value and compare it to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example expressing what @rmaddy already stated in his comment:

```
@implementation YourClass {
  float _sliderValue;
}
- (void)borderSliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
  float currentValue = slider.value;
  if (currentValue > _sliderValue) {
    // right
  } else if (currentValue < _sliderValue) {
    // left
  }
  _sliderValue = currentValue;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I've developed it, check this repo: [Repo](https://github.com/amir-ardalanuk/CentralizeSliderView/tree/main)
[image]

```
slider?.amplitude = 50 
slider?.sliderDidChange = { [weak slider] value in
        if value > 10 {
            slider?.activeColor = .blue
        } else if value < 0 {
            slider?.activeColor = .red
        } else {
            slider?.activeColor = .lightGray
        }
    }
```