# How to implement a slider whose minimum track is begin from center(value=0) not left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

Just something like this.
[image]

Is there any way that just subclass UISlider can achieve this?

**EDIT:**
Maybe I have misleaded you, but this is quite a **UI** problem.

Comment: Set its minimum value to -maximum value and its value to 0

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728163/3901620

Comment: But it wont make the red part start from thumb and end up at the center of slider. It just put thumb at center... @MeharoofNajeeb

Comment: set the current value to 0 and max and min property to +x and -x

Comment: Check this out and let me know if this is what you are looking for.. https://github.com/raxcat/BufferSlider

Comment: It has Solved, Check this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65071910/4316042)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it.

1. create *fakeThumbImageView* *fakeMinTrackImageView* *fakeMaxTrackImageView* and set the frames in `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:`
2. override `setMinimumTrackTintColor:` `setMinimumTrackImage:` and some other methods(6 in total)
3. call `super setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]` and so on in initialize method
4. recommended to make `fakeXXXXImageView.layer.zPosition=1000`

Answer (score 0):

First you set `minimumTrackTintColor = .clear` and `self.maximumTrackTintColor = .clear`. Then you can create a view with the same `width`/`height` of the track and put right below the `UISlider`. With this view you can set `leadingConstraint` and `trailingConstraint` to be compressed in the middle (initial position, when the `UISlider` value is `0.5`). So, whenever the `UISlider` value changes you can re-calculate the constraints to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using Private API,

```objectivec
//  UIView+Swizzle_UISlideriOSVisualElement.m

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

@implementation UIView (Swizzle_UISlideriOSVisualElement)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self swizzleWithClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UISlideriOSVisualElement")
              originalSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"didPerformLayout")
              swizzledSelector:@selector(_UISlideriOSVisualElement_swizzledDidPerformLayout)];
    });
}

+ (void)swizzleWithClass:(Class)targetClass originalSelector:(SEL)originalSelector swizzledSelector:(SEL)swizzledSelector {
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, swizzledSelector);
    
    IMP originalImp = method_getImplementation(originalMethod);
    IMP swizzledImp = method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod);
    
    class_replaceMethod(targetClass, swizzledSelector, originalImp, nil);
    class_replaceMethod(targetClass, originalSelector, swizzledImp, nil);
}

- (void)_UISlideriOSVisualElement_swizzledDidPerformLayout {
    [self _UISlideriOSVisualElement_swizzledDidPerformLayout];
    
    UISlider *slider = ((UISlider * (*)(UIView *, SEL))objc_msgSend)(self, NSSelectorFromString(@"slider"));
    float totalValue = (fabsf(slider.minimumValue) + fabsf(slider.maximumValue));
    if (totalValue == 0.0f) return;
    
    UIView *_minTrackClipView = [self valueForKey:@"_minTrackClipView"];
    UIView *_maxTrackClipView = [self valueForKey:@"_maxTrackClipView"];
    
//    UIImageView *minTrackView = ((UIImageView * (*)(UIView *, SEL))objc_msgSend)(self, NSSelectorFromString(@"minTrackView"));
    UIImageView *maxTrackView = ((UIImageView * (*)(UIView *, SEL))objc_msgSend)(self, NSSelectorFromString(@"maxTrackView"));
    
    float totalWidth = _minTrackClipView.frame.size.width + _maxTrackClipView.frame.size.width;
    
    _maxTrackClipView.frame = CGRectMake(_minTrackClipView.frame.origin.x,
                                         _maxTrackClipView.frame.origin.y,
                                         _minTrackClipView.frame.size.width + _maxTrackClipView.frame.size.width,
                                         _maxTrackClipView.frame.size.height);
    maxTrackView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                    maxTrackView.frame.origin.y,
                                    maxTrackView.frame.size.width,
                                    maxTrackView.frame.size.height);
    
    float percentage = (slider.value / totalValue);
    
    _minTrackClipView.frame = CGRectMake(_minTrackClipView.frame.origin.x + (totalWidth / 2.0f) + ((percentage > 0.0f) ? 0.0f : totalWidth * percentage),
                                         _minTrackClipView.frame.origin.y,
                                         fabsf(totalWidth * percentage),
                                         _minTrackClipView.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/pookjw/UISliderCustomTrack)

[image]